# Como Colocar valor no campo Django vai HTML?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

Olá, estou começando com Django agora e queria saber como faço para passar o valor do banco de dados para um campo Djando usando o HTML para salvar a edição.

```
Na minha View:

@login_required
def editar_aluno(request, id):
    aluno = Aluno.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.POST:
        form = FormAluno(request.POST, instance=aluno)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(lista_aluno)
    else:
        form = FormAluno(instance=aluno)
    return render(request, 'editar_aluno.html', locals())
```

```html
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                          <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" required placeholder="Nome" id="nome" class="form-control" name="nome" style="width:60%">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Pai*</label>
                          <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Pai" id="pai" class="form-control" name="pai" style="width:60%">
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Certo, vamos lá.
Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:
Aqui vamos criar um método para pegar os dados do Banco e passar um dicionário para o html:

```
def arquivos(request):
    arquivos = arquivos.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data') 
    return render(request, 'template/exibir_arquivos.html', {'arquivos': arquivos})
```

No html nós usamos essa sintaxe de {%%} para escrever alguns código e criar uma lógica no html, sendo assim, podemos exibir os dados da maneira que está sendo mostrado no exemplo:

```
{% for arquivo in arquivos %}
    <div>
        <p>publicado em: {{ arquivo.data }}</p>
        <h1><a href="">{{ arquivo.titulo }}</a></h1>
        <p>{{ arquivo.descricao }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Porém... Eu não recomendo que faça isso. No meu caso, eu crio varias rotas com uma API em Django e exibo os dados com JavaScript, assim eu consigo separar o Front do Back. E no caso de uma integração a API já fica pronta.
Espero ter respondido, qualquer dúvida pergunta ai. =D